# How to properly declare a function in C++?

Tags: c++

I'd like to declare a function in my `main.cpp`, so that my `main` function can be the first one in the file. It looks like this:

`main.cpp`

```cpp
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 using namespace std;

string my_function();
int main () {
    my_function();
    return 0;
}
string my_function(string message = "") {
    string response;
    cout << message;
    getline(cin,response);
    return response;
}
```

However, when compiling I get an error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cco8jyj1.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `my_function[abi:cxx11]()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 1.4s with exit code 1]
```

What is wrong?

Comment: `myfunction` and `my_function` are not the same.

Comment: Then please [edit] your post.

Comment: Declaration should match definition.

Comment: typo: change `string my_function(string message = "");` and `string my_function(string message) { your_logic }`

Comment: The forum appears to be plagued with drive-by downvoting without explanation.  I suspect some of the downvoting is done by bots.

Comment: @PonasM I am not the downvoter but was close to becoming one because: this is basic knowledge and is expected of you to cover that part as SO is not a place where you learn a language. Cover the basics first. A good place to start would be these [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). And then come back with a specific problem you are facing.

Comment: I also didn't downvote. But the downvote button is for "lack of research". There are hundreds of examples and tutorials on the net showing and explaining "how functions work".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string my_function();` is declared but is not defined.

It should be:

```
string my_function(string message = "");

...

string my_function(string message) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Better:

- Make default parameters in the declaration, but not the definition.
- Pass strings by const reference so you don't incur an unnecessary
  copy of the string.

Updated:

```
string my_function(const string& message = "");

int main() {
    my_function();
    return 0;
}

string my_function(const string& message) {
    string response;
    cout << message;
    getline(cin, response);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: In this particular case it is just 7 more characters to type. In general case - agree. And don't forget `std::string_view`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution:

```
string my_function(string message = "");

...

string my_function(string message)
 {
    your codes here
 }
```